# Scale circleMarker in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geometry

When you create a circle in Leaflet, you can designate a width that scales (that is when you are zoomed out, the circle is "smaller" keeping in scale with the site it covers).

When you create a circleMarker, the result is a circle that does not scale. How does one make the circleMarker scale like the standard circle?

If not possible, how does one create a layerGroup of circles to achieve the same desired affect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L.CircleMarler` has fixed radius in pixels for any zoom.

But you can create `L.layerGroup` for any class, that implements `ILayer` interface including `L.Circle`. For example:

```
L.layerGroup([L.circle([0, 0], 200000), L.circle([50, 50], 400000)]).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

In leaflet circleMarker function have fix radius with any zoom if you want change radius circle use `{radius: 50.4}`  or if want change weight border circle use `{weight:12}` like this  https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/6btw7zg8/5/

[image]

Comment: Uh? This question is about changing the size with zoom, not the color?